# Why can't a weak_ptr be constructed from a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, weak-ptr

If I understand correctly, a `weak_ptr` doesn't increment the reference count of the managed object, therefore it doesn't represent ownership. It simply lets you access an object, the lifetime of which is managed by someone else.
So I don't really see why a `weak_ptr` can't be constructed from a `unique_ptr`, but only a `shared_ptr`.

Can someone briefly explain this?

Comment: You might be interested in [A Proposal for the World’s Dumbest Smart Pointer](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf)

Comment: This also has to do with potential performance implications (see my answer below).

Comment: @ChrisDrew um… do I understand correctly that `observer_ptr` isn't… *doing anything?* is it basically just syntactic sugar for those who don't like non-owning raw pointers?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yup!

Comment: @ChrisDrew, heh, I suggested the same to Herb Sutter in 2012 but he shrugged it off (actually I wrote about it twice [first here](http://herbsutter.com/2012/06/05/gotw-104-solution/), [then here](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/30/gotw-90-solution-factories/)).

Comment: You can use noshared_ptr/noweak_ptr instead of unique_ptr. https://github.com/xhawk18/noshared_ptr

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`std::weak_ptr` can't be used unless you convert it to `std::shared_ptr` by the means of `lock()`. if the standard allowed what you suggest, that means that you need to convert std::weak_ptr to unique in order to use it, violating the uniqueness (or re-inventing `std::shared_ptr`)

In order to illustrate, look at the two pieces of code:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> shared = std::make_shared<int>(10);
std::weak_ptr<int> weak(shared);

{
*(weak.lock()) = 20; //OK, the temporary shared_ptr will be destroyed but the pointee-integer still has shared  to keep it alive
}
```

Now with your suggestion:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> unique = std::make_unique<int>(10);
std::weak_ptr<int> weak(unique);

{
*(weak.lock()) = 20; //not OK. the temporary unique_ptr will be destroyed but unique still points at it! 
}
```

That has been said, you may suggest that there is only one `unique_ptr`, and you still can dereference `weak_ptr` (without creating another `unique_ptr`) then there is no problem. But then what is the difference between `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` with one reference? or moreover, what is the difference between a regular `unique_ptr` and C-pointers an get by using `get`?

`weak_ptr` is not for "general nonowning resources", it has a very specific job - The main goal of `weak_ptr` is to prevent circular pointing of `shared_ptr` which will make a memory leak. Anything else needs to be done with plain `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 40):

If you think about it, a `weak_ptr` must refer to something other than the object itself. That's because the object can cease to exist (when there are no more strong pointers to it) and the `weak_ptr` still has to refer to something that contains the information that the object no longer exists.

With a `shared_ptr`, that something is the thing that contains the reference count. But with a `unique_ptr`, there is no reference count, so there is no thing that contains the reference count, thus nothing to continue to exist when the object is gone. So there's nothing for a `weak_ptr` to refer to.

There would also be no sane way to use such a `weak_ptr`. To use it, you'd have to have some way to guarantee that the object wasn't destroyed while you were using it. That's easy with a `shared_ptr` -- that's what a `shared_ptr` does. But how do you do that with a `unique_ptr`? You obviously can't have two of them, and something else must already own the object or it would have been destroyed since your pointer is weak.

Comment: And C++ trying to avoid overhead where none is necessary would not burden unique_ptrs with a dynamic allocation for a control block which can hold a common reference count (the way shared_ptrs are burdened).

Answer (score 17):

A `shared_ptr` basically has two parts:

1. the pointed-to object
2. the reference-count object

Once the reference count drops to zero the object (#1) is deleted.

The `weak_ptr` needs to be able to know if the object (#1) still exists. In order to do this, it has to be able to see the reference-count object (#2), if it's not zero it can create a `shared_ptr` for the object (by incrementing the reference count). If the count is zero it will return an empty `shared_ptr`.

Consider the question of when can the reference-count object (#2) be deleted? We must wait until no `shared_ptr` OR `weak_ptr` object refer to it. For this purpose the reference-count object holds **two** reference counts, a *strong* ref and a *weak* ref. The reference count object will only be deleted when both these counts are zero. This means that part of the memory can only be freed after all the weak references are gone (this implies a [hidden disadvantage with `make_shared`](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/make_shared-almost-a-silver-bullet/)).

**tl;dr;** `weak_ptr` depends on a *weak reference count* which is part of `shared_ptr`, there cannot be a `weak_ptr` without a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: In effect, a `weak_ptr` is a `shared_ptr` to the reference count object.

Answer (score 10):

Conceptually, there is nothing preventing an implementation where a weak_ptr only provides access and a unique_ptr controls the lifetime. However, there are problems with that:

- `unique_ptr` doesn't use reference counting to begin with. Adding the management structure for managing the weak references would be possible, but require an additional dynamic allocation. Since `unique_ptr` is supposed to avoid any(!) runtime overhead over a raw pointer, that overhead is not acceptable.
- In order to use the object referenced by a `weak_ptr`, you need to extract a "real" reference from it, which will first validate that the pointer is not expired first and then give you this real reference (a `shared_ptr` in this case). This means that you suddenly have a second reference to an object that is supposed to be uniquely owned, which is a recipe for errors. This can't be fixed by returning a mixed half-strong pointer that only temporarily delays possible destruction of the pointee, because you could just as well store that one, too, defeating the idea behind `unique_ptr`.

Just wondering, what problem are you trying to solve using a `weak_ptr` here?

Comment: Nothing, this is all theoretical.

Comment: `unique_ptr` has overhead. It's just minimal. Bjarne Stroustrup has said as much, and he's a proponent of safer, slightly less efficient code instead of code that's "too clever". He's supremely knowledgeable, and he's fairly good at directing a language in the direction it needs to go to remain relevant. The original direction was total speed with zero weight abstractions. Nowadays, with more and more lower-level code needed to code most things worthwhile and with paying programmers costing more than just buying more hardware, development time with fewer bugs is king even if less efficient.

Comment: Do you have a citation for that? BTW: Quite some effort was put into the core language to guarantee correctness at compile time, which avoids runtime overhead. Move constructors are used in places where pointers were used in C98. Also, think about Rust, which takes this to another level.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt [Here](https://youtu.be/rHIkrotSwcc) is a great talk that discusses `unique_ptr` for quite a while. For starters, the simple code most people would write was *enormous* compared to a raw pointer. After a few smart uses of `noexcept` and move semantics, the code is still less efficient. Stroustrup knows what he's talking about. I won't be able to find the exact minute from the hours I've listened to him talk about C++ though. It's from a talk at CppCon in the last few years. It's a decent *guess* that the compiler will remove all overhead, but it isn't true.

Answer (score 8):

**Looks like everyone is writing here about std::weak_ptr but not about weak poiner concept which I believe is what the author is asking for**

I think that no one mentioned why standard library is not providing weak_ptr for unique_ptr. Weak pointer CONCEPT doesn't disclaims unique_ptr usage. Weak pointer is only an information if the object has been already deleted so it's not a magic but very simple generalized observer pattern.

**It's because of threadsafety and consistency with shared_ptr.**

You just simply can't guarantee that your weak_ptr (created from unique_ptr existing on other thread) will be not destroyed during calling method on pointed object. 
It's because weak_ptr needs to be consistent with std::shared_ptr which guarantee threadsafety. You can implement weak_ptr which works correctly with unique_ptr but only on the same thread - lock method will be unnecessary in this case. You can check chromium sources for base::WeakPtr and base::WeakPtrFactory - you can use it freely with unique_ptr. 
Chromium weak pointer code is most probably based on last member destruction - you need to add factory as a last member and after that I believe that WeakPtr is informed abut object deleteion (I'm not 100% sure) - so it doesn't looks so hard to implement.

Overall using unique_ptr with weak pointer concept is OK IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

No-one has mentioned the performance aspect of the problem yet, so let me throw my $0.02 in.

`weak_ptr` must somehow know when the corresponding `shared_ptr`s have all gone out of scope and the pointed object has been deallocated and destroyed. This means that `shared_ptr`s need to communicate the destruction towards each `weak_ptr` to the same object somehow. This has a certain cost – for example, a global hash table needs to be updated, where `weak_ptr` gets the address from (or `nullptr` if the object is destroyed).

This also involves locking in a multi-threaded environment, so it can potentially be too slow for some tasks.

However, the goal of `unique_ptr` is to provide a **zero-cost** RAII-style abstraction class. Hence, it should not incur any other cost than that of `delete`ing (or `delete[]`ing) the dynamically allocated object. The delay imposed by doing a locked or otherwise guarded hash table access, for example, may be comparable to the cost of deallocation, however, which is not desirable in the case of `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly as with many cases - cause the C++ committee just didn't care and dismissed such usecases.

How it is:
`weak_ptr` was specified in terms of shared-pointer, precluding any attempts at making it a more broadly useful smart-pointer. In C++ conceptually a weak-ptr is a non-owning pointer that *MUST* be converted to a `shared_ptr` to access the underlying object. And as a `unique_ptr` does not support any sort of reference-counting (as it is the unique owner by definition) converting a `weak_ptr` to a pointer with any sort of ownership is not allowed.
It is sadly a bit too late to get good well-named smart-pointers that offer a bit more generality.

But you can create something like that:

To make it safe you would need your own deleter (unique_ptr has the deleter in the type), and a new non-owning `unique_ptr_observer` that changes the deleter. When creating an observer it would register a cleanup-handler as the deleter. That way you can have a `unique_ptr_observer` that can check if the Threadsafety would still be a problem as you would need either a locking-mechanism, create copies for readout, or some other way to prevent the pointer from getting deleted while you are actively looking at it.
(it is so annoying that the deleter is part of the type.......)

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to distinguish reasons for preferring a `unique_ptr` over a `shared_ptr`.

**Performance** One obvious reason is computational-time and memory use.  As currently defined, `shared_ptr` objects typically need something like a reference-count value, which takes space and also must be actively maintained.  `unique_ptr` objects don't.

**Semantics** With a `unique_ptr`, you as the programmer have a pretty good idea when the pointed-to object is going to be destroyed: when the `unique_ptr` is destroyed or when one of its modifying methods is called.  And so on large or unfamiliar code bases, using `unique_ptr` statically conveys (and enforces) some information about the program's runtime behavior that might not be obvious.

The comments above have generally focused on the performance-based reasons that it would be undesirable for `weak_ptr` objects to be tied to `unique_ptr` objects.  But one might wonder if the semantics-based argument is sufficient reason for some future version of the STL to support the use-case implied by the original question.

Answer (score 0):

After many years of c++ programing works, i finally realized that the correct way in c++ world is not to use shared_ptr/weak_ptr for ever. We have spent so many time to fix the bugs caused by the unclear ownership of share_ptr.

The solution is to use unque_ptr and some weak pointer for unique_ptr instead, just as what's expected in this topic.

cpp standard library has no weak pointer for unique_ptr, so i create a very simple, but useful libary here --

https://github.com/xhawk18/noshared_ptr

It has two new smart pointers,

```
noshared_ptr<T>, a new kind of unique_ptr
noweak_ptr<T>, the weak pointer for noshare_ptr<T>
```

Comment: The problem is *unclear ownership*, not `shared_ptr` itself. As a minimum, this can be fixed with a `typedef`. Stroustrup discusses similar issues with `observer_ptr` reinventing the wheel here: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1408r0.pdf .

Answer (score 0):

I demonstrated the problem to myself with a MWE implementing `weak_ptr` on single objects. (I implement it on `X` here, but `X` can be anything that can tell us when it dies, such as a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter).

The ultimate problem however is that at some point we need reference counting on the weak pointers themselves, because while `X` is not shared, the weak pointers *are shared*. This takes us full circle back to using `shared_ptr` again.

Perhaps the only advantage of doing this is that the *intent* of single *ownership* is clearer and cannot be violated, however, [as Stroustrup suggests and is quoted this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837288/in-modern-c-how-should-i-manage-unowned-pointers), this can be hinted at with the `using` statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct ControlBlock
{
    T* Target;
    explicit ControlBlock(T* target) : Target(target) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct WeakReference
{
    std::shared_ptr<ControlBlock<T>> ControlBlock;
    T* Get() { return ControlBlock ? ControlBlock->Target : nullptr; }
};

template<typename T>
struct WeakReferenceRoot
{
    WeakReference<T> _weakRef;
    WeakReferenceRoot(T* target) : _weakRef{std::make_shared<ControlBlock<T>>(target)} { }
    const WeakReference<T>& GetReference() { return _weakRef; }
    ~WeakReferenceRoot() { _weakRef.ControlBlock->Target = nullptr; }
};

struct Customer
{
    WeakReferenceRoot<Customer> Weak{this};
};

int main() {
    WeakReference<Customer> someRef;
    std::cout << "BEFORE SCOPE - WEAK REFERENCE IS " << someRef.Get() << "\n";
    {
        Customer obj{};
        someRef = obj.Weak.GetReference();
        std::cout << "IN SCOPE - WEAK REFERENCE IS " << someRef.Get() << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "OUT OF SCOPE - WEAK REFERENCE IS " << someRef.Get() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```