# Does weak_ptr work alongside unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++14, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, weak-ptr

As I understand it, a `std::weak_ptr` is used as a safe way of referencing memory referenced by a `std::shared_ptr` which may have been deallocated.  Can it be used with a `std::unique_ptr` as well?

Comment: Might find this an interesting read: ["Why can't a weak_ptr be constructed from a unique_ptr?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059343/why-cant-a-weak-ptr-be-constructed-from-a-unique-ptr)

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. A `std::weak_ptr` requires *shared ownership* which `std::unique_ptr` does not possess.

Comment: A unique_ptr is *unique*, that's its purpose in life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As I understand it std::weak_ptr is used as a safe way of referencing memory referenced by shared_ptrs which may have been deallocated.

You understand wrong. `std::weak_ptr` allowes to access object, which ownership is maintained by `std::shared_ptr` without sharing it. Now when you really understand what `std::weak_ptr` does you should understand that your question about `std::unique_ptr` does not make any sense.

Answer (score 3):

There is an equivalent pointer that act as an observer to a `std::unique_ptr`, but will not provide safety in the same way as `std::weak_ptr`.

That pointer is the raw pointer. They are safe to use if they don't outlive the unique owner.

If you need to know if the lifetime of the owner of a raw pointer ended, then no, there is no way and it's not the goal of `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

Unfortunately you will have to use `std::shared_ptr`, and document that the `std::weak_ptr`s should only be locked temporarily.

Comment: Unfortunately or fortunately? Dual ownership is not a feature of `unique_ptr`

Comment: @curiousguy "unfortunately" because you must rely on outer code to never hold onto a locked `std::weak_ptr` to keep the long-term single ownership semantic.

Comment: The distinct syntax and semantic superiority of unique owning smart ptr over shared owning smart ptr is the `release` method (no exception, guaranteed behavior). You can have a unique_ptr_except_locked_weak_ptr, and expect locking to be "short", but by definition a lock (of a weak ref) can outlive something and be the last owner, `release()` cannot be guaranteed, etc.

Comment: @curiousguy Yes, that's why it's unfortunate that you need to waive these advantages and switch over to `std::shared_ptr` if you want weak pointers. It looks like we're agreeing here :)

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting as an alternative. Weak implies multiple owners at least for a small time. And "small" can last as long as the programmer wants. You could outlaw direct duplication of a strong ref and only allow strong->weak->strong, but I don't see the point.

Comment: @curiousguy well I don't see any alternative. There is only `std::shared_ptr`, and trusting the next guy not to lock its `std::weak_ptr`s for too long.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The only constructors available to a `weak_ptr` are one that take either a `shared_ptr` or another `weak_ptr`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/weak_ptr